# ubuntu suspend does not work well after ram upgrade

Tags: upgrade, suspend, ram

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gYDeQ.png)my hp 255 g5 system that runs ubuntu as its only OS.

I recently upgraded the RAM size from 4GB to 8GB by installing another 4GB RAM on the second slot, and ever since the suspend feature does not respond after I suspend it.
It just shows a blank screen and the power LED stays on but the disk LED doesn't come on, the fan is heard working but the system doesn't respond. The newly installed ram works fine when I use it alone and try to suspend everything works fine same as the old ram but when both are in the system the suspend does not respond. I always have to force power off by holding down the power button.
I have tried to upgrade the OS to the latest ubuntu 22.04 LTS version and it still does the same thing.
The swap file has also been increased to 11GB with 1 as its priority.
I don't know what else to do.

Comment: If you have more than two RAM slots it could be essential that the modules need to be in specific slots.  Also, is the second RAM module identical to the first? RAM is supposed to be installed in identical pairs. If you have different models they might not work well together even if they have the same capacity. They may share different timings. Rarely, this can cause hiccups and other problems when you mismatch RAM.  Ideally, the RAM model numbers are also published on your motherboard QVL list.

Comment: I have just two ram slots
also, I tried it with identical ram modules(Samsung & Samsung) it still didn't work but then I hadn't increased the swapfile size.

Currently, the ram modules are of two different manufacturers Hynix(the installed when purchased) and Samsung(extra I bought)

Answer (score 0):

Issue solved by updating the motherboard BIOS. Do it carefully as it may break the motherboard.

In my case I have a Gigabyte Z690 motherboard and failed when upgrading from 16 GB (2x8) to 48 GB (2x16 + 2x8) of RAM Kingston FURY Beast DDR5 4800MT/s CL38.

To solve the issue I did the following steps:

- Format a USB to FAT32
- Go to Gigabyte Z690 official web and download the latest bios version (in my case for the Z690-UD-AX-rev-1x board).
- Unzip and coy the *.FXX file into the USB, then rename this file to GIGABYTE.bin
- Turn off the PC, disconnect the power supply, put USB in the port that is labeled as BIOS (on the back), then turn on the power supply, turn on the PC and access to the BIOS.
- In the BIOS go to the Q-FLASH menu, which is in the bottom right side tabs (for the Gigabyte Z690 board).
- Go to Upgrade BIOS section and select the USB, then click on the GIGABYTE.bin file and continue.
- The PC will turn on and off a few times, DO NOT TURN OFF!, leave it until the PC boots the OS.